# Angular-ui tagging convert array to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, tagging

I am using [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) directive in my template, bound on an object that has a property set as a string. Since `ui-select` will save the values as `Array` in the property, is it possible to transform this value automatically in the model so that when I save it the value will be a string? I tried with `ng-value="model.property.join(',')"` but it has no effects.

The complete code of the element:

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="false" theme="bootstrap" ng-model="user" ng-value="user.keywords.join(',')">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Keywords">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="keyword in user.keywords | filter:$select.search">{{keyword}}</ui-select-choices>
<ui-select>
```

And when I save the object it sends the keywords as: `["keyword", "other"]`